# Unique Left Join Gives Skewed Results

Tags: mysql, join, sum, left-join, union

I'm very perplexed! I have 3 tables that separately give me the results I'm looking for. When I join them (tried join, union, left join, sub query) I get skewed results.

Table 1:

```
SELECT DISTINCT JB.job_id, AR.job_id as jid, SUM(AR.ar_payment_amount) AS sum,
JB.marketing_campaign FROM job_tbl JB LEFT JOIN ar_payment_tbl AR ON JB.job_id = 
AR.job_id WHERE JB.marketing_campaign != '' AND FROM_UNIXTIME(AR.ar_payment_date,'%Y') = 
YEAR(NOW()) GROUP BY JB.marketing_campaign ORDER BY sum DESC LIMIT 10
```

Which gives me the result I'm looking for (just showing one result for this example)

```
[job_id] => 551
[jid] => 551
[sum] => 124440.97024536133
[marketing_campaign] => Roto Rooter
```

Table 2:

```
SELECT DISTINCT JB.job_id, AP.job_id, SUM(price) AS price, AP.vendor FROM job_tbl JB 
LEFT JOIN ap_tbl AP ON JB.job_id = AP.job_id WHERE AP.marked_as_paid = 1 AND 
AP.activity = 'Commission' AND FROM_UNIXTIME(AP.payment_date,'%Y') = YEAR(NOW()) GROUP
BY vendor ORDER BY price DESC LIMIT 10
```

Which gives me the results I'm looking for...

```
        [job_id] => 551
        [price] => 5700
        [vendor] => 436
```

Now when I join them I get a different result

```
SELECT DISTINCT JB.job_id, AR.job_id as arid, AP.job_id as apid, 
SUM(AR.ar_payment_amount) AS sum, SUM(AP.price) AS price, JB.marketing_campaign FROM
job_tbl JB LEFT JOIN ap_tbl AP ON JB.job_id = AP.job_id AND AP.marked_as_paid = 1 AND 
AP.activity = 'Commission' LEFT JOIN ar_payment_tbl AR ON JB.job_id = AR.job_id  AND 
FROM_UNIXTIME(AR.ar_payment_date,'%Y') = YEAR(NOW()) WHERE AP.price != '' AND 
AR.ar_payment_amount != '' AND JB.marketing_campaign != '' GROUP BY 
JB.marketing_campaign ORDER BY sum DESC LIMIT 10
```

Here is the result I get

```
        [job_id] => 551
        [arid] => 551
        [apid] => 551
        [sum] => 130507.02011108398
        [price] => 8200
        [marketing_campaign] => Roto Rooter
```

and here is what the result should be

```
        [job_id] => 551
        [arid] => 551
        [apid] => 551
        [sum] => 124440.97024536133
        [price] => 5700
        [marketing_campaign] => Roto Rooter
```

Any help would be appreciated and this project was due last Friday! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this - I think there were a Problem with the `JOIN` Condition and the `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT 
    JB.job_id, 
    AR.job_id as arid, 
    AP.job_id as apid, 
    JB.marketing_campaign,
    SUM(AR.ar_payment_amount) AS `sum`, 
    SUM(AP.price) AS price

FROM job_tbl JB 
LEFT JOIN ap_tbl AP ON JB.job_id = AP.job_id 
LEFT JOIN ar_payment_tbl AR ON JB.job_id = AR.job_id
WHERE
    AP.marked_as_paid = 1 
    AND AP.activity = 'Commission'   
    AND FROM_UNIXTIME(AR.ar_payment_date,'%Y') = YEAR(NOW()) 
    AND AP.price != '' 
    AND AR.ar_payment_amount != '' 
    AND JB.marketing_campaign != '' 
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4
ORDER BY `sum` DESC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Thanks Benni, If I use it as is it doesn't sum and shows each job_id AND it totals correctly if I add all of them together. If I remove the JB.job_id it gives the same answer as before but is grouped properly. (also should be GROUP BY) Any other thoughts?

Comment: Same...gives me all the job_id and not grouped by marketing_campaign.

Comment: Please provide some `CREATE TABLE...` and `INSERT...` statements for a test-case.

Comment: Sorry for the delay....I had to get access to the tables. Where do I send or post the dump?